# Four per page to print

Tags: positioning, printing

I made an invitation for an event in LaTeX, with output at 4.25in x 5.5in.  I'd like to place four of these in a 2x2 grid, and get an 8.5in x 11in document for printing.  No margin changing, no resizing, just stick the pages together.  One would think this should be easy, but I haven't had any luck actually doing it...

Some utilities I've tried:

- `pdfjam --nup 2x2 out.pdf` (output has dimensions 8.27in x 11.69in. I can't tell what's gone wrong, but I don't want this off center)
- `imagemagick` with `+append` and `-append`.  The PDF gets rasterized and the text doesn't come out well.

Any ideas?  The option to set the page size originally was

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.25in,paperheight=5.5in,margin=0.7in]{geometry}
```

Comment: Look at the `pdfpages` package.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  Sorry for the duplicate question, though the answer accepted there doesn't solve my problem, because pdfnup/pdfjam don't precisely respect the page size when combining as indicated.

Comment: I'd say leave it to your printer (driver). Any postscript (compatible) printer should offer you these options at printing time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that your invitation was called `invite.pdf` and created using:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.25in,paperheight=5.5in,margin=0.7in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]% The invitation
\end{document}
```

Now create `printing.tex` resembling:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge[nup=2x2]{invite,invite,invite,invite}
\end{document}
```

The key in the final component is to merge `invite.pdf` in order to duplicate it on the page.